# MongoDB batch size

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, pymongo

I am not really getting the concept of batch size, I wonder what would happen if I set the batch_size to be 1 million

```
x = c.find({}, batch_size=1000000)
```

Comment: Have you checked out the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#iterate-the-returned-cursor) and the [pymongo documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor.batch_size)?

Answer (score 2):

Batch size parameter has some use, here what I believe to by the 2 core concepts behind it and why you'd sometimes want to use it:

1. Memory usage - imagine you're querying millions of documents, a simple server might not have enough memory to load handle them all at once, by specifying batch size you could split your procesing into more manageable chunks.
2. Performance - again image a very large query that scans (and matches) many documents, without the batch size you'd have to wait for the scan to complete before you can start processing the results all at once, by splitting the scan into chunks Mongo can give you an answer quick so you can start processing and not be blocked.

Obviously both of these examples are somewhat niche, and usually most people do not bother with batch size configuration.

If you "don't get it" then it probably just means you don't need it. - this advice is also probably true for various aspects in code :).